# SQL Server 2012: Import error

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, sql-server-2012

I am trying to import txt file and am using import method into SQL Server and am having a tough time converting string into `datetime` format as one of column within SQL Server is in `datetime` format. It is giving a type 2 error. Please advice, should I go convert the format into something else within import method or should I try using a new table

This is the format of the data type of the sql server table

```
[int     NOT NULL,
 [varchar   (32) NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [varchar   (512) NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [bit    NULL,
 [bit    NULL,
 [bit    NULL,
 [varchar   (256) NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [varchar   (256) NULL,
 [varchar   (256) NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [varchar   (16) NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [varchar   (128) NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [bit    NULL,
 [bit    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [varchar   (64) NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [varchar   (64) NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [varchar   (16) NULL,
 [char  (1) NULL,
 [char  (1) NULL,
 [varchar   (16) NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [char  (1) NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [bit    NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [varchar   (128) NULL,
 [bit    NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [varchar   (64) NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [varchar   (64) NULL,
 [varchar   (512) NULL,
 [varchar   (128) NULL,
 [varchar   (128) NULL,
 [varchar   (32) NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [varchar   (128) NULL,
 [varchar   (128) NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [bit    NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [varchar   (512) NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [float  NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [datetime   NULL,
 [int    NULL,
 [datetime   NULL

5590    AACMT 2005-C6A  503 56  MMC Borrower LLC, Marsh USA Borrower LLC, Seabury & Smith Borrower LLC, Mercer HR Consulting Borrower LLC and Mercer MC Consulting Borrower LLC 15  0.05701 0.056896    2   475000000   361 475000000   359000000   20050929    360 20351011    2   430026303.9 359000000   0.69    398 398 0   1   1   1.36    1.44        0.731   0.66        0.069227    0.058535    0.058535        45014186    9512000 20110101    20110331    650000000   20051101    20051029    360 360 0.05701 0.000114    1   0.0001  1   N   N   N   YM@25b(284) 20120213        0.05701         2036013     0                                                                               0               20051101    20051101    20100101    20101231    1   26392357        38048000    1.44    1.44    38048000    38048000            1   26392357        38048000    1.44    1.44    38048000    38048000    20110101    20110331    1   6598090     9512000 1.44    1.44    9512000 9512000 20351011        429312084       1   1166 Avenue of the Americas (Marsh)     H           0   N   Y   27935   AACMT 2005-C6   1   343001412   430026304   20120211        0.05701 0.056896    2042983 714220  2757203                         3               CMSA        N                                                   475000000                                                       1166 Avenue of the Americas (Marsh) N                           Marsh & McLennan Companies, Inc.                                    Wells Fargo Bank    Wells Fargo Bank    77  1   650000000   20051101    20351011    0   N       L(24), YM@25b(336)          0       1.441629        1.36    0.11129         284                 38048000    20101231    38048000    20101231
```

Comment: Please add a tag indicating which version of SQL Server you are using. 2005, 2008, 2012?

Comment: **SHOW US SOME CODE** and a sample of the file you're importing! Also: what are you using to import the file? C# code? Integration Services? Something else?

Comment: Yes ok - thanks for the table structure - but we really need to see the **FILE YOU'RE TRYING TO IMPORT** and the **CODE** doing the import, to understand what's might be going wrong ....

Comment: sure marc, I am relatively new here, is there a way to attach the txt file

Comment: as it is about 226 columns

Comment: attached is one of the lines, let me know if u wud want me to paste more rows

Comment: attached is one of the lines, let me know if u wud want me to paste more rows, Also I am using the SQl server Import and Export Wizard

Comment: hey Marc please do let me know if u need anything else. Any solution to this wud be really helpful

Comment: What is the precise error message? Usually it tells you which row and/or column is the problem: the sample row you posted may be completely fine. You might want to consider importing the data with [bcp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) instead, because it makes it easier to send error rows to a separate file for examination (using the `-e` switch).

Answer (score 0):

> Please advice, should I go convert the format into something else
>   within import method or should I try using a new table

My advice is to import it as a varchar and then work with the data in SQL to convert it to the proper format. You'll have an easier time sorting out where the conversion error is coming from then through the importer.